# Spring: convert from JSTL(forEach) to angular.js(ng-repeat)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to angular.js,  I have a spring MVC application and I will like to switch from jstl to angular.js, I started this way

```
<table>
        <c:forEach var="list" items="${list}">
            <tr class="alt" ><td >${list.name}</td><td >${list.value}</td> </tr> 
        </c:forEach>
 </table>
```

to

```
 <table ng-app="" id="users">
        <tr ng-repeat="x in list">
             <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.value }}</td>
        </tr>

 </table>
```

Comment: And your angular code? Start with defining an app module and controller from where you can fetch the data using either $http service or a factory.

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to write the information directly in HTML you can add a tag  with the required script.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      angular.module('AppNameHere', [])      
      .controller('exampleController', function() {
        this.list = [{
            name: 'Fool',
            value: '12'
          },
          {
            name: 'Bar',
            value: '15'
          }];
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="AppNameHere">
    <table id="users" ng-controller="exampleController as example">      
      <tr ng-repeat="x in example.list">
        <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.value }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, as @Vaelyr said, AngularJS is commonly used to fetch data from server (using ajax or something similar) and show the results on the page:

```js
// By default, you can use only 1 module per page.
angular.module('AppNameHere', [])
  // service to load the data from server
  .factory('exampleFactory', function($q){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    
    // TODO: Load async...
    var list = 
      [{
        name: 'Fool',
        value: '12'
      },
      {
        name: 'Bar',
        value: '15'
      }];
    
    deferred.resolve(list);
    
    return deferred.promise;
  })

  // controller to show the data on the page
  .controller('exampleController', function(exampleFactory) {
    var controller = this;
    controller.list = [];
    
    // When the data is fetched from the server...
    exampleFactory.then(function(list) {
      // bind to the page
      controller.list = list;
    });
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="AppNameHere">
    <table id="users" ng-controller="exampleController as example">      
      <tr ng-repeat="x in example.list">
        <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ x.value }}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```